# Definition of PU(2,1)?

Tags: matrices, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, complex-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I know what the unitary group of complex matrices $U(n)$ is, and what $PU(n) = PSU(n) = SU(n)/(\mathbb{Z}/n)$ is. However, I found in an article mentioned $PU(2,1)$, the group of bi-holomorphisms of the two dimensional complex ball. What is the definition of $PU(2,1)$, how does it differ from $PU(2)$, and how does it act on the complex ball?

Comment: The isomorphisms here aren't _quite_ correct - while it's true that $PU(n) = PSU(n)$, the second equivalency isn't; rather, they're isomorphic to $SU(n)/(\mathbb{Z}/n)$, and $SU(n)\not\equiv U(n)$.

Comment: Yes, I corrected the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$U(p,q)$ is the symmetry group of the Hermitian form of type $(p,q),$ defined by
$$|| (z_1,\ldots,z_n)||^2 = |z_1|^2 + \cdots + |z_p|^2 - |z_{p+1}|^2 - \cdots
- |z_{p+q}|^2.$$

Let's consider the case $p = n, q = 1$.  Any vector in $\mathbb C^{n+1}$
can have positive, zero, or negative norm, and pretty clearly this depends only
on the complex line spanned by $z$.  We can thus speak of lines of positive, negative, or zero norm.

The lines of negative norm then form a copy of the complex $n$-ball,
sitting inside $\mathbb C P^n$.    The property of having negative norm is
invariant under $U(n,1)$, and so we get an action of $PU(n,1)$ on the $n$-ball,
compatible with the usual action of $PGL(n+1, \mathbb C)$ on $\mathbb C P^n$.

---

[This link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783034804806-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1353802-p174510707&ei=tc8UU77WHsa2yAH7_4CICg&usg=AFQjCNE5GapoeQ69Fy8yzGz7rFzvS-lzCA&bvm=bv.61965928,d.aWc) seems helpful.  (Not sure if it's freely available.)

Comment: I see, instead of leaving invariant the standard inner product, U(n,m) leaves invariant the product defined by (u,v) = $\sum_{1}^{n} u_{i}v_{i} - \sum_{n+1}^{n+m} u_{j}v_{j}$ ? And thanks for the link, it is available.

Comment: @user79303: Dear user, Yes, provided you take the complex conjugate of all the $v$'s.  And I'm glad the link worked. Cheers,